# Does Matrix3D has transpose method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I cant find method to transpose Matrix3D, but there are all other methods like scale, multiply and other.

Does transpose method really not present or I just blind?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way in this situation would be using of SharpDX. This is the easiest way to have transposition in matrices.